# How do I find info about "sticky bits" from within Linux without having to use Google?

Tags: linux, man

When I type:

```
$ man -k sticky
```

I get:

```
sticky: nothing appropriate
```

Surely there is information within the Linux OS somewhere (without having to go to Google) about [sticky bits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit) - what they are, how to set them on directories, etc.

Of course I've found relevant info on this topic on Wikipedia and elsewhere by using Google, but I want to know how to look it up within Linux itself (I'm using CentOS v6.3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
man 2 chmod
```

Or, if you feel like digging through source,

```
vi /usr/include/sys/stat.h
```

Possibly also helpful (though absent from CentOS 6, per DanielBeck's comment):

```
man 8 sticky
```

Answer (score 3):

```
man 1 chmod
```

http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod :

> Restricted Deletion Flag or Sticky Bit
>
> The restricted deletion flag or sticky bit is a single bit, whose
>   interpretation depends on the file type. For directories, it prevents
>   unprivileged users from removing or renaming a file in the directory
>   unless they own the file or the directory; this is called the
>   restricted deletion flag for the directory, and is commonly found on
>   world-writable directories like /tmp. For regular files on some older
>   systems, the bit saves the program's text image on the swap device so
>   it will load more quickly when run; this is called the sticky bit.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

If you have Emacs (or any Info browser) and the [GNU C Library Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/) installed, you can do this:

1. Start Emacs and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> (*or click “Help > More Manuals > All Other Manuals (Info)”*) to start its built-in Info reader.
2. Press <kbd>m</kbd> (*or click on “Info > Menu item > Other”*)
3. Type `libc` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Type <kbd>i</kbd> (*or click on “Info > Index > Lookup a String…”*)
5. Type `sticky` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You will get this text:

> ‘S_ISVTX’
>
> This is the "sticky" bit, usually 01000.
>
> For a directory it gives permission to delete a file in that
>   directory only if you own that file.  Ordinarily, a user can
>   either delete all the files in a directory or cannot delete any of
>   them (based on whether the user has write permission for the
>   directory).  The same restriction applies--you must have both
>   write permission for the directory and own the file you want to
>   delete.  The one exception is that the owner of the directory can
>   delete any file in the directory, no matter who owns it (provided
>   the owner has given himself write permission for the directory).
>   This is commonly used for the ‘/tmp’ directory, where anyone may
>   create files but not delete files created by other users.
>
> Originally the sticky bit on an executable file modified the
>   swapping policies of the system.  Normally, when a program
>   terminated, its pages in core were immediately freed and reused.
>   If the sticky bit was set on the executable file, the system kept
>   the pages in core for a while as if the program were still
>   running.  This was advantageous for a program likely to be run
>   many times in succession.  This usage is obsolete in modern
>   systems.  When a program terminates, its pages always remain in
>   core as long as there is no shortage of memory in the system.
>   When the program is next run, its pages will still be in core if
>   no shortage arose since the last run.
>
> On some modern systems where the sticky bit has no useful meaning
>   for an executable file, you cannot set the bit at all for a
>   non-directory.  If you try, ‘chmod’ fails with ‘EFTYPE’; see
>   [Setting Permissions](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setting-Permissions.html).
>
> Some systems (particularly SunOS) have yet another use for the
>   sticky bit.  If the sticky bit is set on a file that is *not*
>   executable, it means the opposite: never cache the pages of this
>   file at all.  The main use of this is for the files on an NFS
>   server machine which are used as the swap area of diskless client
>   machines.  The idea is that the pages of the file will be cached
>   in the client’s memory, so it is a waste of the server’s memory to
>   cache them a second time.  With this usage the sticky bit also
>   implies that the filesystem may fail to record the file’s
>   modification time onto disk reliably (the idea being that no-one
>   cares for a swap file).
>
> This bit is only available on BSD systems (and those derived from
>   them).  Therefore one has to use the ‘_BSD_SOURCE feature select
>   macro to get the definition (see [Feature Test Macros](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html)).